# html Image folder path no set in setsrc picture

Tags: html, image

**im trying to set image path in picture setsrc but its not set and image is not showing**

**my code :**

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="pngimg.png" media="(max-width: 600px)">
    <source srcset="assents\images File\Student hub.jpg" media="(max-width: 1500px)">
    <source srcset="assents\images File\Stupid School logo.png">
    <img src="img_smallflower.jpg" alt="Flowers">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute should contain a valid URL. Since space characters are not allowed in URLs, you have to [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) them.

You can try

```
    <source srcset="assents\images%20File\Student%20hub.jpg" media="(max-width: 1500px)">
    <source srcset="assents\images%20File\Stupid%20School%20logo.png">
```

Or try changing the filename to the one without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using whitespaces when naming your folders

Whitespace character code is %20, so you should rename your path to

```
<source srcset="assents\images%20File\Stupid&20School%20logo.png">
```

However, I would better rename your folders without using whitespace to prevent pain in the future.
Valid names could be:
images, images-file, imagesFile, images_file, etc.

After renaming files, the source tag would look like:

```
<source srcset="assents\images\stupid-school-logo.png">
```